# Symfony 4.1 Custom twig error template

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I'm trying to override twig html error templates as per [the symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html)

So I tried to override the views like for other third party bundles by creating the following files in 'templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception' :

- error.html.twig
- error404.html.twig

However the default html twig error templates show up when I trigger a 404 error in production mode.

Testing with the /_error/{statusCode} route in dev mode displays my custom templates correctly.

Comment: did you clear cache?

Comment: yes both symfony and browser

Comment: Production cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I found out that it was an issue with FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle. Using `composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle dev-master` solved the issue